# What does the total membrane current vs time plot of an action potential look like?

Tags: neuroscience

What does the total membrane current vs time plot of an action potential look like? I see that there are voltage vs time plots, but I can't seem to find the current plots.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out panel b for total current, panel c for K+ and panel d Na+ currents separated...

[image: APcurrent]

This is from this website: [imageWebsite](http://www.physiologyweb.com/lecture_notes/neuronal_action_potential/neuronal_action_potential_pharmacological_inhibition_of_na_and_k_channels.html)

Comment: Could you please also provide a link to your source in case someone wants to read more about how these currents are measured?